# Как сделать бота?

Tags: php, c++, c

Хочу сделать бота. Для игры  Silkroad. Знаю частично C++, C#. С чего мне начать?

Comment: *прочитал "как сделать бога"... надо больше спать...*

Comment: ты не один такой

Comment: Я вроде сегодня выспался (наконец-то), но тоже так прочитал.

Comment: Ахахахахаха

Answer (score 4):

Частичных знаний не хватит для подобной задачи. Вам нужно много понимать в клиент-серверных технологиях, разбираться конкретно с выбранной вами игрой, анализировать трафик и преодолевать МАССУ проблем, возникших походу дела. Пока вы с этим всем разберетесь, наверняка кто-то с опытом в подобных делах уже напишет бота за вас, если его конечно еще нет на всяких "жуках" и прочих подобных сайтах.

Comment: Для этой игры много ботов но они все устаревают я хочу сделать приватного бота для себя и друзей))) Подскажите в сё таки с чего начать я готов учить долго долго просто я хочу ни писать бота  это моя цел которую я себе поставил))

Comment: Я понятия не имею о ваших навыках и знаниях и на подобный вопрос напрашивается фраза: начните сначала =) Ну а по делу сперва попробуйте себе представить, как вообще устроены подобные игры, проанализируйте данный процесс и найдите пробелы в своих знаниях, ну и восполняйте их естественно. Есть бот с открытым кодом под названием L2NET, написанный на С#(при помощьи гугла его легко найти и скачать), но он правда для Линейдж, хотя не думаю, что это принципиальная разница и для старта думаю будет в самый раз, как пример.
ПС: Очень сомневаюсь в успехе вашей затеи.

Comment: незнаю не знаю может у меня что нибудь получиться )) Объясню по конкретней   с чего мне именно начать какой раздел из C++ (C#) мне надо учить я просто не знаю как построенны боты

Comment: Для этого изначально не С смотреть нужно, а продумать логику работы твоего бота. т.е. расписать по пунктикам что он должен делать, как себя вести на той или иной странице, в общем представь что ты бот и ходи по страницам, смотри формы, которые нужно заполняй нужными данными и жми на отправить.

Comment: Это мморпг игра и здесь нет никаких страниц, веба и пхп. Все построено на клиент-серверном взаимоднействии сервака и клиентов. Собственный протокол передачи пакетов, собственное шифрование и тд. Начните именно с этого - это целая тема в любой технологии. Вы разбираетесь в этом? Судя по всему нет - вот и учите! Что уж более конкретней? Пример бота с исходниками я давал выше, вот тема для изучения - дерзайте!

Answer (score 0):

Поищи в Интернете информацию, как они делаются. Изучи тот язык, который для этого нужен. Если этой информации в Интернете нет, то проще будет написать свою игру, чем разбираться в том, как устроена чужая игра без исходных кодов.

А вообще, цель странная. Ну напишешь ты бота, допустим, за год. Немного поиграешь и надоест. Лучше напиши что-нибудь более полезное.

Comment: Игры я не умею писать

Comment: Да и зачем это нужно для человека-геймера, который планирует ближайшие несколько лет провести в виртуальном мире? :)

Comment: >Игры я не умею писать

 И ботов тоже. По-любому придётся учиться, чтобы что-то написать.

Comment: Само по себе написание программок это очень интересная игра.

Answer (score 0):

предлагаю посмотреть программное нажатие клавиш вот тебе бот и готов

Comment: А как этот бот будет видеть уровень и стрелять? Наугад?